# Number of different binary matrices

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I have interesting task:

You're given a integer N. Find a number of different binary matrices of size NxN that satisfy the following conditions:
1. Each row contains 3 ones.
2. Each column contains 3 ones.

Do any know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you know the approaches to solve this?

Comment: Try this paper http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v12i1r29